# ReactJs Responsive PDF Viewer

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I trying to show pdf document using ReactJs.
I tried this libraries and its not works like expected .

- react-pdf
- @react-pdf/renderer
- reactjs-pdf-reader
- @phuocng/react-pdf-viewer --> this works great only on Desktop , its not works on mobile.

I need to use library that allows to :

- zoom
- download button
- works on mobile
- shows page numbers

Thanks :)

Comment: You can create your own customized version of pdf viewer using Mozilla's PDF reader. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: @SelvaS  How to create it for React js ?